# VS code find-and-replace: Replace in selection gives unexpected result when selecting multiple lines?

Tags: visual-studio-code, replace, find

In VS Code, when I use find-and-replace to replace all instances within a selection, I get an unexpected result. If my selection includes parts of multiple lines, the find-and-replace is applied to every line that overlaps my selection.

Example:
Replace all instances of "X" with "Y" in the bold part of the following text:

> AAX**Y**
>
> **BBXY**
>
> CCXY

I expect the following:

> AAX**Y**
>
> **BBYY**
>
> CCXY

but I get this:

> AAY**Y**
>
> **BBXY**
>
> CCXY

Does this happen to other people, and is there an easy way for me to get my expected result?

Comment: I have the same behavior, I think you should make an issue for this because it is not correct within the selection. A selection has a line-char start and end, and char is not always 0 and line-length

Comment: Thanks! You mean on GitHub? https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues

Comment: @rioV8 If I understand correctly, there is some combination of a bug report and feature request about this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/80008. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, you can up vote the question to let the developers know that more people see this as a bug. I think they have used the same method as used in the indent by TAB routine, that works with partial selected lines

Comment: I put in a feature request for this fix and some other find-and-replace stuff. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/116827